# Converting Hex Data

Tags: python

I'm looking over some example code for a really small script to convert some logged data that's saved as hex values in a csv.  I was trying to see how the script is converting these hex values to the engineering units and there's a lambda function that I don't get what it is doing. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing here but honestly these bitwise operators are not something I've worked on at all as I am only a very occasional user of Python.

`b16 = lambda x: int(x,16)`

`s16 = lambda x: -(b16(x) & 0x8000) | (b16(x) & 0x7fff)`

The data is pulled into a pandas dataframe and the s16 function applied to each column. I get that the b16 function is converting it to a decimal value but the s16 I don't get.  Are the and functions setting a min/ max of the output? I'm just used to converting hex to decimal and then just mathing on that so forgive my ignorance here!

Comment: " I get that the b16 function is converting it to a decimal value" it is not. it is converting it to an `int` object.